# How to manage try-catch centrally in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there any possible way to get all server exceptions which has been occur in catch block.

role.js

```
try{
  throw new Error('Error happen...!');
}catch(err){
  console.log(err)
}
```

Can we get the above catch block error in the app.js file ??

Comment: Synchronously thrown exceptions can be caught centrally fairly easily.  It would depend upon your server framework on what the best way to do that.  Asynchronously thrown exceptions are a different beast entirely and a different strategy would be used for those which will require some cooperation from the asynchronous code and is a ton easier if all asynchronous work uses promises.

Comment: To help you appropriately, we need a lot more specifics on the coding situation.  There is NO generic top-level solution for handling all uncaught exceptions, both synchronously thrown and asynchronously thrown in nodejs.   And, proper resource cleanup on error (like database connections or file handles) always requires local exception handlers anyway.  And, sending a response to an http request that encounters an exception will also require a somewhat local response handler (in the context of the request).

Answer (score 0):

You can look at `process.on('uncaughtException', () => {})` to get all exceptions that bubble to the top.

However, it's generally not a good idea to have a catch-all exception handler.

Relevant docs: [Link](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception)

Comment: I had already tried it but it not works. Is there any other way ??

Comment: Could you add a bit more detail in your question? For example, use cases, code sample etc? Do you want to track all the caught exceptions?